# How can I echo out the selected date

Tags: php

does anyone know how I would echo out the `selected` date as text with the date month and year separated outside of the form? I tried echoing out `$date` `$month` and `$year` outside of the form however this doesn't give me the correct date thankyou for the help

```
<?
$date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14','16-03-28','16-04-14','16-04-28',
'16-05-14','16-05-28','16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14','16-07-28','16-08-14','16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28',
'16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');
    $currentdate = date('y-m-d');
    echo $currentdate;
    ?>
    <form>
    <select style="width:200px;">
    <?php
    foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
        if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1])) {
            $selected = "selected";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
        echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($d)) . "</option>";
        echo 'the current billing period is';

    }
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do overall? I saw you posted this earlier, but I am slightly confused. Are you trying to echo all of the billing dates in the future into a select box?

Comment: basically this is the dropdown where a user can select a billing date and view the statement for the 14 day period what im trying to do is echo out the date which is selected as plain text so i can then grab all the purchases made from the date.

Comment: I think you should change your year to be the 4-digit year instead (2016).  Also, how are you generating your date list?  And why?  Just out of curiosity.

Also, you are echoing `the current billing period is` inside of the `<select />` tag.  That should be outside of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your loop add a `$selected_int` variable like so:

```
foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
    if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1])) {
        $selected = "selected";
        $selected_int = $i;
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
    echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($d)) . "</option>";
    echo 'the current billing period is';

}
```

Then, you can reference it like:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date[$selected_int]));
```

**Addition**

I know you've already accepted the answer, but I also wanted to make a suggestion now that I see what you are using the `$date` for.  Since you know the start date, and it is in 14-day periods, it would be easy to write that as part of the loop.

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y').'-01-01'); //First day of the year, for the sake of argument.

$interval = 14;

for ($i = 0; date('Y') == date('Y', strtotime($start_date.' +'.($i * $interval).' days')); $i++) {//While this year is equal to the start date's year with the added interval [If I knew what your logic here was I could offer a better suggestion]
    if ($currentdate >= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date.' +'.($i * $interval).' days')) && (date('Y') < date("Y", strtotime($start_date.' +'.(($i + 1) * $interval).' days')) || $currentdate < date("m/d/Y", strtotime($start_date.' +'.(($i + 1) * $interval).' days')))) {
        $selected = "selected";
        $selected_int = $i;
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($start_date.' +'.($i * $interval).' days')) . "</option>";
}
```

Basically, this takes the start date, shows it as the first date option, then adds 14 days to it with each pass through.  Your `if/else` statement should still be the same.  It checks to see if you are on the last interval of the year, or if the current date is less than the next interval, and also that the current date is greater than the current interval.

After your loop, you can get the date by:

```
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($start_date.' +'.($selected_int * $interval).' days'));
```

I know it seems like a lot, but it would save you from having to make a date array to begin with.

Comment: @LewisTyler haha, that was the fastest accept I ever think I got.  ;)  Glad it helped.

Comment: @LewisTyler Also made a suggestion if you wanted to check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested defiantly looks a lot easier than the method I'm currently using however the script doesn't select the correct option from the dropdown. defiantly going to use this though much cleaner.

Comment: @LewisTyler Glad to hear that.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Use strtotime instead list.

```
....
// list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($d)) . "</option>";
....
```

EDIT: Additional information - your code requires a lot modification and likely some structure changes but assuming this is for testing a method and "how to do" instead a final product.

You need to submit the selected date, catch it in the script and use the selected date to do what you need - i.e. retrieve data from database - and this should give you some idea.

```
<?php
    // You need to create these dates by using another method. You cannot hard code these. You can create it with date functions easily.
    $date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14','16-03-28','16-04-14','16-04-28','16-05-14','16-05-28','16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14','16-07-28','16-08-14','16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28','16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');

// Checking if we have a posted form, with the button name user clicked 
if (isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])) {
    // This is your selected day - use it  where you need:
    $selectedDate = $_POST["selectedDate"];

    // This is where your model start singing and gets necessary info for this date - just printing here as sample
    print $selectedDate;

    // I need dropDownDate to compare in the SELECT to preselect the appropriate date
    $dropDownDate = strtotime($selectedDate);

} else {
    // First time visit, preselect the nearest date by using current date
    $dropDownDate = time();
}

?>
<form method="post">
<select name="selectedDate" style="width:200px;">
<?php
foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
    if ($dropDownDate >= strtotime($d) && 
            (!isset($date[$i+1]) || ($dropDownDate < strtotime($date[$i+1])))
        ) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }

    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
    echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($d)) . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note that I added a "submit" type input (to submit the form) and changed form method to "post", finally named SELECT as "selectedDate". I also changed your date comparison code line in the loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion I have implemented this into my script? however do you know the answer to this question? thankyou

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Please check my EDIT in the answer. should give you a good starting point - but you need to improve the code.